# How does AngularJS send its requests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, request, firebug

I was just curious, how does AngularJS send requests to fetch HTML from another page and not showing any request in Firebug -> Net Panel.

I have a `<div>` with `ng-view` attribute and I passed a url of another page and I was expecting an ajax request, which I can trace within the Net panel.

But there's no request listed within the Net panel while AngularJS was able to get the HTML from that URL. How did it work?

Comment: Sorry Guys... It was weird... but It worked when I checked it through localhost, and it showd the GET request ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS makes a XHR request. Probably the requests are not logged in Firebug, or all requests are made in the initial page load.

Comment: yes, it should send any kind of request, but Firebug should have traced this. I have set up Persist Option on, but it don't show nothing. :)

Comment: You are right!! It was my browser problem, Its FF 33 beta, and its not even showing CSS, Images requests.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the needed template/HTML was included in the page already.

one can to so with JavaScript, or simpy include it as a script template like this:
(from the documentation)

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
   Content of the template.
</script>
```

or they have filled the [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) by hand, or with a tool

Comment: Template Code is in separate html file, and url of that file is passed in Routing Thing.

http://www.thinkful.com/learn/angularjs-tutorial-build-a-gmail-clone/Routing-and-Dependency-Injection

I was checking this directly, without any server or localhost. And it was getting html from that template without showing any request.

Comment: @Sandeep, If I open up the network tab in the dev tools, and reload the page, I see all the network requests coming by. 
The only way to introduce a template/html into a angular app without doing a request, is pre-loading it using the techniques I described in my msg.

Comment: The techniques you told are great. It was my fault, the browser has some problems I guess because its not even showing CSS requests etc. Its Firefox 33 beta...